# What happens in PHP when short-circuit && and || are mixed in the same expression?

Tags: php

Are && and || evaluated strictly left-to-right or are the && operators evaluated first (most tightly)? I'm writing a recursive-descent parser so the answer will determine how the code looks.

Example:

```
if ($a || $b && $c)
```

Is the expression evaluated as `($a || $b) && $c`, or `$a || ($b && $c)` ?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to just try it yourself?

Comment: The point of this forum is (or should be) to help everyone, not just the person who asked the question. I noticed that it is difficult to find an answer to this question on the web, and since I need the answer anyway, thought I would ask it. Does this offend you in some way?

Comment: `&&` gets evaluated first, before an `||` unless you specify parentheses.

Comment: Wouldn't [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) on precedence be the place for the definitive answer?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the manual describing operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) `&&` is evaluated before `||`, one can easily look that up. Many languages have operator precedences, not all of them are the same.

Answer (score -1):

A comment indicates that the evaluation order is `$a || ($b && $c)` .

Comment: The expression should be evaluated as `$a || ($b && $c)`. https://3v4l.org/WpM6q